# command stdout to /dev/null

Tags: linux, bash, stdout, null

I have very simple command which generating STDOUT which i want to do `/dev/null` but somehow it's not working or i am missing something here.

```
$ ldapsearch -Y GSSAPI -b "cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=example,dc=com" "uid=foo" | grep krbPasswordExpiration | tail -n1 | awk '{print $2}'
SASL/GSSAPI authentication started
SASL username: admin@EXAMPLE.COM
SASL SSF: 256
SASL data security layer installed.
20200608022954Z     <---- This is my krbPasswordExpiration value.
```

But if you see in above command `SASL` line which is just stdout which i want to do `/dev/null` so i have tried following but it seems not working.

```
$ ldapsearch -Y GSSAPI -b "cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=example,dc=com" "uid=foo" | grep krbPasswordExpiration | tail -n1 | awk '{print $2}' 2> /dev/null
```

what other way i can get rid of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be aware of *what* command is doing the output to stderr and make sure the redirection is associated with that command.

You can think of pipes as having ( ) around the commands

So

```
a | b | c
```

can be thought of as

```
( a ) | ( b ) | (c )
```

(That's not literally how it works, but it's a mental model).

And the redirection happens inside the brackets.

So it's clear that

```
( a ) | ( b ) | ( c 2>/dev/null )
```

doesn't redirect the error message from "a"

but

```
( a 2>/dev/null) | ( b ) | ( c )
```

does

And so, your command redirected the error from the `awk` command.  You really want to redirect the error from `ldapsearch`.

So

```
$ ldapsearch -Y GSSAPI -b "cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=example,dc=com" "uid=foo" 2>/dev/null | grep krbPasswordExpiration | tail -n1 | awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: Damn it, good catch, i didn't realize that i am doing bunch of `|`  thank you for second set of eye :)